# How to Calculate Scrollview width and height on every scroll in iOS

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, cgpoint, cgfloat

I have `Scrollview` using for displaying images along with two buttons **previous** and **next**.

Now my problem is when the user is scrolling the image I want to identify whether it is from right to left scroll or vice versa. For this purpose I have to calculate scrollview `contentOffset` and scrollview `frame size` but I don't know how to calculate those values.
Still now I used:

```
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0){}
```

this method.

need any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView1 willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate;
{
    CGFloat pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width;

    float fractionalPage = scrollView.contentOffset.x / pageWidth;

    NSInteger page = lround(fractionalPage);

    if (previousPage != page){

        if ([scrollView.panGestureRecognizer translationInView:scrollView.superview].x > 0){

            NSLog(@"-1");
        } else {

            NSLog(@"+1");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the solution But it works fine when user Drag completely if user stop dragging before reaching the next image it should not perform the action but using this code it does.I am using **count** variable +/- based on left on right action.so if user stop dragging initially count value also changing.I hope you understand my problem.

Comment: NSInteger previousPage; .h file

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you are scrolling Horizontally you will get to know whether you are going next or previous depending upon velocity.x

> velocity.x > 0 ?(int) _currentIndex + 1 :(int) _currentIndex - 1;

```
-(void) scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {


    CGFloat xAxisVisible= self.uiScrollDetails.contentOffset.x;
    self.currentIndex=xAxisVisible/320;

    NSLog(@"Dragging - You are now on page %i",(int) self.currentIndex);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. Let me know how to get currentIndex value.